# Deploying a smart contract from the 2nd user account

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

how do I deploy a smart contract using a 2nd account?

```
const xxx = artifacts.require("xxx");
var web3 = require('web3');

module.exports = function (deployer, accounts) {
  deployer.deploy(xxx, {from: accounts[1]});
};
```

There is an error.

> Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***
>
> "xxx" -- Provided address e is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or it's an indirect IBAN address which can't be converted. -- Reason given: Custom error (could not decode)..

May I know how to fix it?

Also, what is the difference between accounts[1] and web3.eth.accounts[1]?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to remove the error by adding 'network' as one of the parameters in the function.

```
module.exports = function (deployer, network, accounts) {
```

Let me know if there are alternative ways to do it.